# ios7 styling for phonegap/backbonejs application

Tags: javascript, html, css, backbone.js, ios7

I am creating an app with phonegap, backbone.js and rails for the back end. I have been searching for ios7 html/css styling but haven't had much luck. This website http://www.idangero.us/framework7/ is ideal for what I want, but it doesn't seem like it will integrate nicely with backbone. I have also heard of app-framework through intel but that one seems to be lacking some of the styling I want. Does anyone have any good suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here they promise that to version 1.0 it will be possible to use it with MV* frameworks without a hassle.

https://github.com/nolimits4web/Framework7/issues/62

Comment: hopefully they do soon, their platform looks very promising